# PCA 'unnormalize' weights

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, pca, eigenvalue

When computing a PCA on several prices, we usually normalize them first.

Let's say I got the weights (eigenvectors) for the PC5. This weights are made from normalized prices.

If I believe PC5 is too high, and I want to short the portfolio, how to 'unnormalize' weights such that I can take the real size of each asset.

I saw some attempts but none of them is mathematically sound.

Thank you in advanced!